# Do rays fire if you have no materials of their type?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

If you have no transmission materials, does Cycles still process transmission rays? Is there any speed increase to disabling a ray type if you don't have any materials that use it?

Comment: [By definition](https://www.blender.org/manual/render/cycles/settings/light_paths.html) you need transmissive objects in order to have transmission rays, so AFAIK no.

Comment: Are you talking about branched path tracing?